# xsd:ID in Relax NG Schema

Tags: xml, schema, xsd, relaxng

I have the following xml file

```
<bookshop>
<book bid="1"> Programming in C# </book>
<book bid="2"> programming in Java </book>
<authors>
 <author bidref="1"> person1 </author>
 <author bidref="2"> person2 </author>
 <author bidref="1"> person3 </author>
</authors>
</bookshop>
```

then I made the following Relax NG schema

```
start=element bookshop{
element book {attribute bid{xsd:ID},
              text}
element authors{
    element author { attribute bidref{xsd:IDREF},
                         text}
               }}
```

However, it always gives me error said that value of attribute bid is invalid must be an XML name without colons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've fixed the errors in your XML example. Your schema can't validate the XML you've given there because it's, well, wrong. Anyway, that's probably at least partly a copy and paste error. The schema I think you mean is below (one or more marker and sequence comma inserted):

```
start=

element bookshop
{
    element book {attribute bid {xsd:ID}, text}+,

    element authors
    {
        element author { attribute bidref {xsd:IDREF}, text}
    }

}
```

As an aside, this sort of 'russian doll' schema is horribly unmaintainable. If you are using RelaxNG you'd be better off with named patterns.

Now, your fundamental problem here is that you've modelled the attributes `bid` and `bidref` as `ID` and `IDREF` respectively. These types hark back to DTDs. An ID type is defined [as matching the 'Name' production](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#id) which is defined (in the same document) as:

```
NameStartChar ::=       ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | 
    [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | 
    [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | 
    [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
NameChar ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | 
    [#x203F-#x2040]
Name     ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

*In simple terms that says "you can't start an ID with a number nor can an ID be just a number". XML ID (and IDREF) values must start with a letter.*

Your schema, btw, might be better expressed as:

```
bookshop.content = (book+, authors)
bookshop = element bookshop {bookshop.content}

book.bid = attribute bid {xsd:ID}
book.content = (book.bid, text)
book = element book {book.content}

authors.content = author+ 
authors = element authors {authors.content}

author.bidref = attribute bidref {xsd:IDREF}
author.content = (author.bidref, text)
author = element author {author.content}
```

Comment: Hi Nic.  I know this thread is a little old, but I've been banging my head against xsd:ID not allowing a colon (":") in an id attr.  Most of the W3 pages, like the one you linked to, indicate that a colon is valid.  Then I found this, http://www.w3.org/XML/xml-19980210-errata#E98, which I take to mean: "you shouldn't use a colon in an id attr., but you should be allowed to."  Given that interpretation, I'm stumped why JING says I can't.  I hope this is a worthy comment.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Zachary, didn't you ask this as a question somewhere recently or did I imagine that? The explanation is a little complex for a comment - ask a question and I'll try to explain!